# Unable to click on checkboxes in Google MDL Table generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following javascript which loads a table with rows generated by reading a JSON dataset.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.getJSON('/GetQueue.ashx')
            .done(function (data) {
                var tbl = $('#queueBody');

                data.forEach(function (i) {
                    var tblRow = $("<tr>");

                    var tdCheck = $("<td>");
                    var tdCheckLabel = $('<label>');
                    var tdCheckBox = $('<input>');
                    var spanFocusHelper = $('<span>');
                    var spanBoxOutline = $('<span>');
                    var spantickOutline = $('<span>');
                    var spanRippleContainer = $('<span>');
                    var spanRipple = $('<span>');

                    // mdl-checkbox__box-outline
                    tdCheckLabel.addClass('mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-data-table__select mdl-js-ripple-effect--ignore-events is-upgraded');
                    tdCheckLabel.attr('data-upgraded', ',MaterialCheckbox,MaterialRipple');

                    tdCheckBox.addClass('mdl-checkbox__input');
                    tdCheckBox.attr('type', 'checkbox');

                    spanFocusHelper.addClass('mdl-checkbox__focus-helper');
                    spanBoxOutline.addClass('mdl-checkbox__box-outline');
                    spantickOutline.addClass('mdl-checkbox__tick-outline');

                    spanRippleContainer.addClass('mdl-checkbox__ripple-container mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-ripple--center"');
                    spanRippleContainer.attr('data-upgraded', ',MaterialRipple');

                    spanRipple.addClass('mdl-ripple');

                    tdCheckBox.appendTo(tdCheckLabel);
                    spanFocusHelper.appendTo(tdCheckLabel);
                    spanBoxOutline.appendTo(tdCheckLabel);
                    spanRippleContainer.appendTo(tdCheckLabel);

                    spanRipple.appendTo(spanRippleContainer);
                    spantickOutline.appendTo(spanBoxOutline);

                    tdCheck.append(tdCheckLabel);

                    tblRow.append(tdCheck);
                    // now add all the other columns
                    tblRow.append("<td class='mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'>" + i.Manifest + '</td>');
                    tblRow.append("<td class='mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'>" + i.PatientNumber + '</td>');
                    tblRow.append("<td class='mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'>" + i.Filename + '</td>');
                    tblRow.append("<td class='mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'>" + i.PracticeName + '</td>');
                    tblRow.append("<td class='mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric'>" + i.MessageSource + '</td>');
                    tblRow.appendTo(tbl);
                    // $('#queueHolder').append('<p>' + i.Filename + '</p>');
                });

                componentHandler.upgradeDom();
            });
    });
</script>
```

The following is a sample of the HTML Generated by that javascript

```
<td>
    <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-data-table__select mdl-js-ripple-effect--ignore-events is-upgraded" data-upgraded=",MaterialCheckbox,MaterialRipple">
        <input class="mdl-checkbox__input" type="checkbox">
        <span class="mdl-checkbox__focus-helper"></span>
        <span class="mdl-checkbox__box-outline">
            <span class="mdl-checkbox__tick-outline"></span>
        </span>
        <span class='mdl-checkbox__ripple-container mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-ripple--center"' data-upgraded=",MaterialRipple">
                <span class="mdl-ripple"><span>
        </span>
    </label>
</td>
<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">228471</td>
<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">2610759</td>
<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">261075963308592015-12-11 144533</td>
<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">HOLBROOK SURGERY</td>
<td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">INPATIENT</td>
</tr>
```

But when I click on the checkboxes - nothing happens.

However if the table row I not generated dynamically, but is present in the source of the page - then that can be clicked on.

So how do I get dynamically generated data to be clickable.

I have tried

```
componentHandler.upgradeDom();
```

but this does not seem have made any difference.

Comment: `componentHandler.upgradeDom();` what do you have in it?

Comment: Nothing that is the whole line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an issue using JQuery and the mdl CSS library. Resorting to vanilla JavaScript when creating objects seems to deal with the issue.